# Expanding h4 content according to td

Tags: html, css

I have added a `<h4>` tag in a `<td>` element and rotated 90 degrees, 
so that both the `<td>` and `<h4>` are rotated.

Issue:

If my `<h4>` content is bigger or contains a space it comes in a new line.
How I can fix this? I need to put all the content in a single line in the `<td>`.

Comment: code or fiddle available??

Comment: @user3138481 you can `scale` the size of` h4` using `css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nowrap` Attribute is what you need.

```html
 <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Poem</th>
        <th>Poem</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td nowrap><h4>Never increase, beyond what is necessary</h4></td>
        <td>Never increase, beyond what is necessary, the number of entities required to explain anything</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please accept the answer so that others facing same issue can use this solution :)